# Finding the list where the minimum is

Tags: list-manipulation

So I have the following lists:

TolRin=0.2;
TolRout=0.1;
TolC={0.02, 0.05, 0.4};
TolL={0.02, 0.05, 0.3};

I want to find the minimum on this lists and I know that Min can do that https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Min.html

However I also want to know IN WHICH LIST that minimum is and, knowing the list, finding the position.
Any clue on how to do that?

Comment: It would be better if you use your existing question [function-that-finds-the-minimum-of-various-lists-and-returns-the-list-where-the](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/257814/function-that-finds-the-minimum-of-various-lists-and-returns-the-list-where-the) than make new question if you have any follow up or clarification. This question seems like an exact duplicate of your other one. is it not?

Comment: People didn't understand the question, as I fear the existing comments will prevent a quick answer I did a new question. I'll delete the previous one.

Comment: `Ordering[#, 1] & /@ {{1, 4, 5}, {4, 3, 2}, {1, 2, 3}}`

Answer (score 2):

You can find this using the **Minimum** and **Position** command.

*For Example*,

```
a={{1, 4, 5}, {4, 3, 2}, {1, 2, 3}}
```

To find the minimum of the list 'a':

```
Min[a] or Min[{1, 4, 5}, {4, 3, 2}, {1, 2, 3}]
```

Then It gives the answer 1

Then use the **Position** command to find out the index,

```
Position[{{1, 4, 5}, {4, 3, 2}, {1, 2, 3}},1]
```

Solution is {{1, 1}, {3, 1}}

Short Answer:

```
In[1]:=Min[a] or Min[{1, 4, 5}, {4, 3, 2}, {1, 2, 3}]

Out[1]:=1

In[2]:=Position[{{1, 4, 5}, {4, 3, 2}, {1, 2, 3}},1]

Out[2]:={{1, 1}, {3, 1}}
```